# @font-face doesn't work in Firefox (but exact same code works on another site)

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, typography

I have two sites using the same exact code for @font-face. The font files are hosted on the respective sites and the paths are correct.

One works, one doesn't. (And of course it works on my personal site and not the clients!)

I'd really appreciate some fresh perspective on this!

### Where it WORKS:

The site: http://example.com/

The CSS file: http://365.example.com/index.php?css=photos/style.v.1275845154

The relevant code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'JournalRegular';
    src: url('./themes/fonts/journal.eot');
    src: local('Journal Regular'), local('Journal'), url('./themes/fonts/journal.ttf') format('truetype');
 }
body{
    background: url("http://labs.example.com/personal/library/images/BG.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'JournalRegular', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, sans-serif;
    color: #999;
 }
```

### Where it DOESN'T WORK:

The site: http://www.example.org/

The CSS file: http://www.example.org/wp-content/themes/theme/style.css

The relevant code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'JournalRegular';
    src: url('http://example.org/wp-content/themes/theme/fonts/journal.eot');
    src: local('Journal Regular'), local('Journal'), url('http://example.org/wp-content/themes/theme/fonts/journal.ttf') format('truetype');
 }
.title h1{
    float:left;
    background:url(images/blt-ttl1?.png) no-repeat 0 4px;
    margin:0px 0 5px;
    /* padding:8px 0 8px 34px; */
    color:#bd5f01;
    letter-spacing: .5pt
    font:24px/26px 'JournalRegular', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

Any help would be so greatly appreciated!

Comment: It works in Chrome/IE/Safari. 
Also, I tried a relative URL for the fonts, and it didn't work.

Comment: Why the absolute URLs in the second one and the relative URLs in the first?

Comment: Absolute in the second because it's a WP site and sometime WP gets finickey.

Comment: YES! I switched to relative URLs and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: my WP site has never given me `@font-face` problems with relative URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font-embedding, that is, the `@font-face` requires the font file to be created on a per-domain basis.

That's because the some fonts might have copyright issues.

Comment: Right, it was hosted on the domain, but it got caught because I used a absolute URL instead of relative. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

the ultimate solution to this problem is:

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
```

Copy the code into the .htaccess file, upload it, and your're done: firefox will show your @font-face fonts.

Hope it works for everyone!

Comment: was the most convenient solution for me, too.

Comment: One additional note: on our server we had to enable the headers module before it took effect. Naturally, of course. Just FYI - it wasn't enabled by default.

Answer (score 4):

firefox accepts only relative links for font-face by default.. [link](http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=%40font-face_support_in_Firefox)

Use [HTTP access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) or relative links