# Firefox cannot load @font-face?

Tags: firefox, font-face

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@font-face fonts only work on their own domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892691/font-face-fonts-only-work-on-their-own-domain)

I've been working on my blog template and i'm using @font-face, but it seems that the fonts **doesn't load in Firefox**. But it does on Chrome, IE, Safari

Here's the @font-face that i used

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
    src: url('https://sites.google.com/site/directorybesttheme/font/BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('https://sites.google.com/site/directorybesttheme/font/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('https://sites.google.com/site/directorybesttheme/font/BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('https://sites.google.com/site/directorybesttheme/font/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('https://sites.google.com/site/directorybesttheme/font/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Any idea why and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions:

1. [@font-face doesn't work in Firefox (but exact same code works on another site)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104546/font-face-doesnt-work-in-firefox-but-exact-same-code-works-on-another-site)
2. [@font-face fonts only work on their own domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892691/font-face-fonts-only-work-on-their-own-domain)

By default, Firefox will only accept relative links. If you want to use absolute links or include fonts from different domains, you need to send these fonts with Access Control Headers - https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
    src: url('./font/BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('./font/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('./font/BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./font/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('./font/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I was using that code and it works. Don't forget to upload the fontkit to your font folder.